# Conflict between UL and LI Styles

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web project that has a css file called Style.css. Inside this file, a style series is defined for UL and LI, which has been used in most parts and sections of the project. Its structure is as follows:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

li {
    list-style: none
}
```

And in one part of the project I had to use a **TreeView**. This Object requires a style with the following structure:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-inline-start: -.5em;
}

li {
    list-style: none
}
```

My question is how should I use these two styles so that the second style is used only in TreeView and has no other effect on other parts of the website. Special thanks to all the friends.

Comment: What about using `class` or `id`?

Comment: If possible send a sample style to define the ID. Because I did not work with CSS and I am not a professional. Thanks @Sana Mumtaz

Answer (score 1):

you can use class for `ul` :

```css
.treeView {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-inline-start: -0.5em;
}

.treeView li {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <ul class="treeView">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```